# 'offline_access' value in scope using openid for getting refresh token from B2C Azure Active Directory is not working

Tags: openid, adal, angular5, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to implement authentication with Azure B2C Active Directory. Everything is working fine I can login and get the access_token from the B2C active directory with particular policy. But when I try to pass value "offline_access" in scope inside login url for getting the refresh toke it returns a error message and I cannot login.
I am using ADAL (Azure Directory Authentication Library) of Angular 5 to authenticate to Azure AD.

[Here is image my angular ADAL configuration codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lnml.png)

[Here is the image of issue I am getting when trying to pass "offline_access" value in scope inside url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJLxx.png)

complete error message:

> *http://localhost:4200/dashboard#error=invalid_request&error_description=AADB2C90012%253a+The+scope+'openid+offline_access'+provided+in+request+is+not+supported.%0D%0ACorrelation+ID%253a+05f9f8b0-a8a0-4fdc-9cca-50a4e81a929c%0D%0ATimestamp%253a+2018-01-17+04%253a35%253a36Z%0D%0A&state=a878cc7f-6d87-47e6-9965-d2536aa06ea6*

Am I missing something here? Or there is another way to get the refresh token ?

Comment: Can you please provide the request URL that is being sent to AAD B2C service? You can typically trace it using Fiddler or similar tool.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, you should use [the Azure AD v2.0 Authentication Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-libraries) -- otherwise known as MSAL -- rather than use [the Azure AD v1.0 Authentication Library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-libraries) -- otherwise known as ADAL -- with Azure AD B2C.

Secondly, for a single-page application, Azure AD B2C doesn't issue a refresh token.

Instead, as described at [Azure AD B2C: Single-page app sign-in by using OAuth 2.0 implicit flow > Refresh tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-spa#refresh-tokens), the single-page application must refresh the ID and access tokens using a hidden iframe.

This token refresh is handled by MSAL.

Comment: When i tried to get refresh token using hidden iframe. I have "Refused to display 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/te/1a118090-7001-4b0d-8fdb-22f2598d838b/oauth2/authresp?id_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6Ino0NHdNZEh1OHdL.................a24026a89dbf' in a hidden iframe because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'." error

Comment: You must include the `prompt=none` parameter in the hidden request. If the hidden response includes the new tokens, then the single-page app can continue. If the hidden response includes an `error` property, because Azure AD B2C can't issue the new tokens, then you must redirect the visible frame to Azure AD B2C for sign-in.

Comment: I have added prompt=none as a parameter in the hidden request. Even adding prompt parameter as none is producing this error.